# Expression Trees:How to check if index exists?

Tags: c#

I am writing expression trees to validate Json object. Here is checking if  `stuff["Address"]["State"]== "NY"`

```
var stuff = JObject.Parse("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' }, 'Age': 42 }");

ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(JObject), "g");
var indexexpr = Expression.MakeIndex(parameterExpression, typeof(JObject).GetProperty("Item", new[] { typeof(string) }), new[] { Expression.Constant("Address") });
var secondlevel = Expression.MakeIndex(indexexpr, typeof(JToken).GetProperty("Item", new[] { typeof(string) }), new[] { Expression.Constant("State") });

var conversion = Expression.Convert(secondlevel, typeof(string));

var result = Expression.Equal(conversion, Expression.Constant("NY"));

var fun =Expression.Lambda<Func<JObject, bool>>(result, new[] {parameterExpression}).Compile();
var istrue = fun(stuff);
```

Problem: For json objects sometimes the indexes does not exist. For example , if I do `stuff["Home Address"]["State"]== "NY"` on the same object Expression will throw an exception

Quesion: How can I check if the index property exist before trying to evaluate on the basis of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you need is:

```
(string) (stuff["Address"] != null ? stuff["Address"]["State"] : (JToken) null) == "NY"
```

This can be constructed like this:

```
var stuff = JObject.Parse("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' }, 'Age': 42 }");

ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(JObject), "g");
var indexexpr = Expression.MakeIndex(parameterExpression, typeof(JObject).GetProperty("Item", new[] { typeof(string) }),
            new[] { Expression.Constant("Address2") });                                    
var secondlevel = Expression.MakeIndex(indexexpr, typeof(JToken).GetProperty("Item", new[] { typeof(string) }),
           new[] { Expression.Constant("State") });

// stuff["Address2"] != null
var nullCheck = Expression.NotEqual(indexexpr, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(object)));
// stuff["Address2"] != null ? stuff["Address2"]["State"] : (JToken) null
var finalExpression = Expression.Condition(nullCheck, secondlevel, Expression.Default(typeof(JToken)));
// (string) (stuff["Address2"] != null ? stuff["Address2"]["State"] : (JToken) null)
var conversion = Expression.Convert(finalExpression, typeof(string));
// final expression
var result = Expression.Equal(conversion, Expression.Constant("NY"));

var fun = Expression.Lambda<Func<JObject, bool>>(result, new[] { parameterExpression }).Compile();            
var istrue = fun(stuff);
```